# Entender JPA y relaciones ManyToOne y OneTomany

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

estoy integrando un proyecto con Spring, usando Hibernate JPA y dentro de las relaciones que hay dentro tengo un error porque no se está asignando correctamente el atributo, soy nuevo utilizando JPA para estar relacionando las tablas

**clase hija donde se planea tener la llave foránea dentro de los atributos**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tipo_credito")
public class Credito {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

@Column(name = "nombre", nullable = false, length = 50)
private String nombre_evento;

@ManyToOne
private Events id_eventos;

public Credito() {

}
```

**clase padre **

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "eventos")
public class Events {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

@Column(name = "nombre", nullable = false, length = 50)
private String name;

@Column(name = "fecha", nullable = false, length = 50)
private Date date;

@ManyToOne(targetEntity = Validacion.class)
private Validacion id_validacion;

@ManyToOne(targetEntity = PlanEstudios.class)
private PlanEstudios id_plan_estudios;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "eventos", cascade =CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval=true)
private List<Credito> id_credito;

@Column(name = "horas", nullable = false, length = 50)
private int horas;

public Events() {
    
}
```

Así mismo tengo un error para asignar una entidad, no está correctamente definida, por lo que el crearla se está volviendo una tarea complicada

Comment: Podrias colocar una traza del error que te esta presentando. Asi viendo un poco tu codigo diria que te faltan atributos, como que campo mapea la relacion de un lado y otro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo resolví haciendo referencia al mismo nombre de la variable que estamos pasando, es decir, la variable que por ejemplo está en el ManyToOne que es id_eventos debe ser la misma variable que tengo en la clase de eventos creada osea en la clase events debo materar esta variable id_eventos

Comment: No olvides aceptar tu respuesta, y modifica el título de tu pregunta para que otros usuarios con un problema similar puedan encontrar tu pregunta más fácilmente.